# How to perform a lower_bound operation on the second elements of a vector of pairs in C++?

Tags: c++, search, vector

One can copy all the `v[i].second` elements to a new vector and then do the `lower_bound` operation on the new vector and as the position of the particular value we are searching for would be the same in both vectors so it is reasonable to do. But if the vector has many elements then copying would be costly.

So, I want to know the syntax to perform a `lower_bound` operation on a `vector<pair<int,int>>` type of container if possible (specially only on the second elements of the vector).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int myValue = 42;  // value to search for.
std::lower_bound(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), myValue,
  [](const pair<int,int>& a, int b) {
    return a.second < b;
  });
```

This assumes the vector is sorted by `element.second`.

Comment: @Evg Indeed. Corrected now.

Comment: What is the return value of this lower_bound operation? I used `auto it = lower_bound(...)` . But I can't dereference `it` to print the value it points to.

Comment: It points to the first element whose second component is >= `myValue`, or `end()` if there is none such. How do you try to print it, and what happens when you try? It would be best if you show a [mcve]

Comment: My first thought was `(*it).second`. It didn't work and says "error: no match for call to '(main()::<lambda(const std::pair<int, int>&, const std::pair<int, int>&)>) (std::pair<int, int>&, const int&)'|"

Comment: I'm not sure what you are talking about. [This code](https://rextester.com/VKTDV48762) works for me. If you need further assistance, show the exact code you are running, and quote the exact text of any error message.

Comment: It worked, I was careless not to read your code thoroughly. But you used int b as the second parameter of your function. Recently I learnt how to sort a vector of pairs and in that function both parameters were const pair<int,int> type. And then we would compare a.second < b.second. And also you didn't qualify b as a constant. Can you please describe the reason of this difference?

Comment: For the comparison function used by `std::lower_bound`, the first parameter is the element of the sequence, and the second is the value you are searching for. These may be the same or different types. With `std::sort`, two parameters passed to the comparison are both elements of the sequence, naturally of the same type.